# Can a PHP CLI script detect / fire a callback on script halt?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

Is it possible for a PHP CLI script to detect if it is about to be stopped? This should work for exiting the script using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, or whether the script ends naturally. Ideally I'm looking for some sort of callback to fire before the script is completely halted.

My original thought that I could have a single class with a `__destruct()` function like the following:

```
<?php

class ExitHandler {
    public function __destruct() {
        toOut('Script Halted'); // Writes to STDOUT
    }
}

$exitHandler = new ExitHandler();

// ...

?>
```

However, while testing showed that it would fire when a script naturally exited, it would not trigger for if a script was halted with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>:

```
php -r "Class Abc { public function __destruct() { echo 'Bye.'; } } $x = new Abc();"
=>Bye.

php -r "Class Abc { public function __destruct() { echo 'Bye.'; } } $x = new Abc(); while(true) { sleep(1); fwrite(STDOUT, 'Tick'); }"
=>TickTickTick^C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that [pcntl_signal](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php) will allow you to handle regular (non kill -9) shutdowns

Example taken from above link:

```
<?php
// tick use required as of PHP 4.3.0
declare(ticks = 1);

// signal handler function
function sig_handler($signo)
{

     switch ($signo) {
         case SIGTERM:
             // handle shutdown tasks
             exit;
             break;
         case SIGHUP:
             // handle restart tasks
             break;
         case SIGUSR1:
             echo "Caught SIGUSR1...\n";
             break;
         default:
             // handle all other signals
     }

}

echo "Installing signal handler...\n";

// setup signal handlers
pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, "sig_handler");
pcntl_signal(SIGHUP,  "sig_handler");
pcntl_signal(SIGUSR1, "sig_handler");

// or use an object, available as of PHP 4.3.0
// pcntl_signal(SIGUSR1, array($obj, "do_something"));

echo"Generating signal SIGTERM to self...\n";

// send SIGUSR1 to current process id
posix_kill(posix_getpid(), SIGUSR1);

echo "Done\n";

?>
```